# Grid Layout Group not working If I deactivate it and then activate again in unity Unity 2021.3.6f1

Tags: unity-game-engine

I used Unity Layout Group It works fine if that's gameobject is enabled by default, If I disabale during play through inspector and enable it again it stuck and nothing worked.. Everything else still works fine but grid not work.
Same thing happening via script..
I'm using Unity: `2021.3.6f1`

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by stuck?

Comment: GridView freezed, but outside of that grid everything works perfectly

Comment: I still don't understand. In my mind grids are pretty static. Is it animated or something?

Comment: There's no animation only you can scroll left and right and there's some buttons in it

Comment: So you can't scroll or click the buttons after re-enabling?

Comment: yes, if it's enabled by default it's works but If we disable and enable it again it stops working..

Comment: A picture of your object hierarchy before and after could be interesting to see.